# Why Cast() doesn't invoke the constructor?

Tags: c#, xml, linq, list, casting

If I do:

```
IList<WSACLI_ComunicazionePersonale> Comunicazioni = (from XmlNode n in m_oNode.SelectNodes("m_Detail_Row")
                     select new WSACLI_ComunicazionePersonale(n)).ToList();
```

it works perfect, building my list of `WSACLI_ComunicazionePersonale` object!

But, if I do:

```
IList<WSACLI_ComunicazionePersonale> Comunicazioni = m_oNode.SelectNodes("m_Detail_Row").Cast<WSACLI_ComunicazionePersonale>().ToList();
```

the list is `null`. Seems that `Cast()` doesn't call the constructor?

Comment: Why would you expect it to?

Comment: Have you overloaded the explicit operator to define the cast in _WSACLI_ComunicazionePersonale_?

Comment: What in the documentation indicated that it would?

Comment: @CédricBignon It wouldn't work even if you had; user defined explicit conversions are a compile time construct, not a runtime construct.

Answer (score 6):

Because casting does not create a new object - it just "re-types"<sup>*</sup> the existing object so you can use it in a different way.  There's no construction involved.

You can treat a `Cat` as a generic `Animal`, but it does not create a "new" `Cat`.  Plus, it's still a `Cat` - you're just *interacting* with it like it were a generic `Animal`.

The reverse *may* also be true - if someone gives you an `Animal` you could interact with is a such.  You could *try* to interact it as if it were a `Cat`, but if it is *really* a `Dog`, you can't (legally) treat it as a `Cat`.

<sup>* By re-type I mean change the type you're considering the object to be - the underlying type of the object does not change.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You do not create a new object: the **instance** remains the same. Only the type of the variable that references your instance is modified.

Answer (score 0):

Your second piece of code should read something like this if you want the same functionality as the first:

```
IList<WSACLI_ComunicazionePersonale> Comunicazioni = m_oNode
    .SelectNodes("m_Detail_Row")
    .Select(n=> new WSACLI_ComunicazionePersonale(n))
    .ToList();
```

There is no cast because you cannot cast the node to your object. In your first example, you created a new instance and passed the node to the constructor.

Comment: That is essentially his first example in Method Syntax.

Comment: Actually, it is his second example, but with the Cast replaced with a Select.... which is what his first example was in LINQ syntax. (It all depends on which way you want to look at it)

Answer (score 0):

Constructor is only invoked when a new instance of [`Object`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e5kfa45b.aspx) is created in .Net language, whereas `Casting (Type Casting)` is a a method of changing the existing type of a object to different Type

Type Casting (On Wikipedia)

> In computer science, type conversion, typecasting, and coercion are
>   different ways of, implicitly or explicitly, changing an entity of one
>   data type into another. This is done to take advantage of certain
>   features of type hierarchies or type representations. One example
>   would be small integers, which can be stored in a compact format and
>   converted to a larger representation when used in arithmetic
>   computations. In object-oriented programming, type conversion allows
>   programs to treat objects of one type as one of their ancestor types
>   to simplify interacting with them.

```
Animal animal = new Cat();

Bulldog b = (Bulldog) animal;   // if (animal is Bulldog), stat.type(animal) is Bulldog, else an exception
b = animal as Bulldog;          // if (animal is Bulldog), b = (Bulldog) animal, else b = null

animal = null;
b = animal as Bulldog;          // b == null
```